# Zend Framework double escaping

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, escaping, magic-quotes-gpc

I use Zend framework with doctrine for a project , the problem is that when i insert in database a string like O'Shea it inserts O\'Shea.
 I guess this is because of double escaping. One when i get the post and one when i use doctrine, why when i print_r($_POST) i get values already escaped?

the syntax of doctrine query is:

```
$req = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$company = Doctrine::getTable('Project_Model_Companies')->find($company_id);
$company->name = $req['name'];
$company->save();
```

Please help me how to avoid this double escaping, or what is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: maybe magic quotes is enabled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [magic_quote_gpc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) is turned on.

You can check wether magic qoutes are enabled or not with [get_magic_quotes_gpc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)

```
echo (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? 'Magic qoutes Enabled' : "Magic qoutes Disabled";
```

I would highly recommend [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Try the following .htaccess file directive :

```
php_value magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Or in your php.ini

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Comment: There's a minor typo in the .htaccess directive:
`php_value magic_quotes_gpc Off`
(note the missing `s` from quotes)

Comment: Thank's Attila. Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Benjamin Cremer answer:

Sometimes magic quotes can't be disabled, use this code in your index file to ensure this issue will never bother you again:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  function stripslashes_deep($value)
  {
    $value = is_array($value) ?
          array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
          stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
  }

  $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
  $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
  $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
  $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
}
```